# ajax request with pdf string creation

Tags: ajax, fpdf

I Have an ajax request like this:

```
$.ajax({
        url: (URL + "enrollmentCourse/addEnrollment"),
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        data: formData,
        error: function (request, status, error) {
            console.log("Error "+request.responseText+" "+error);
        },
        success: function (json) {
        console.log ("success");
},
        contentType: false,
        processData: false
    });
```

Inside this request I create on the fly a pdf with fpdf ( I use this command):

`$invoice = $me->createProgramAndInvoicePdf($enroll['id'], 'S');`

The param S creates a string with the pdf.
The ajax call should return the status of the request, so I do this:

```
$data[] = array(
            STATUS => $checkAll,
            CHECK_FIRSTNAME => $checkFirstname,
            CHECK_LASTNAME => $checkLastname,
          
        );

echo json_encode($data);
```

The problem is that when I return to the ajax call I have an error, because the ajax request returns also all the pdf file and at the end my object $data,so I get this error:

`SyntaxError: Unexpected token % in JSON at position 0`

Comment: Just modify the script to not return the PDF.

Comment: I need the pdf because I send a mail and I want to attach the pdf

Comment: I meant "don't send it to the browser".

Comment: Yes but I don't know how...normally the patameter S in fpdf should return the pdf as a string and not to the browser